# Axios interceptor - shows sign in form

Tags: reactjs, axios

The axios interceptor is not working correctly for me.

Here is my code for refreshing JWT tokens:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
    async config => {
        const value = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
        console.log("Sending request: " + value);
        config.headers = {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${value}`,
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
        return config;
    },
    error => {
        return Promise.reject(error)
    });

// Response interceptor for API calls
axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
        console.log("Response OK!");
        return response;
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log("Error, refreshing access token!");
        const originalRequest = error.config;
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
            console.log("Retry: true")
            originalRequest._retry = true;
            let axiosInstance = axios.create();
            return axiosInstance
                .post('/auth/token/refresh/', {refresh: localStorage.getItem("refresh_token")})
                .then(res => {
                    if (res.status === 200) {
                        console.log("Access token:" + res.data.access);
                        store.dispatch(setAccessToken(res.data.access));
                        return axios(originalRequest);
                    }
                });
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
    });
```

The token gets refreshed correctly, however everytime I make the first request (after the access_token expired) it always shows me the browsers 'Sign In' form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with the interceptor, but at backend site.
Basic Authentication was enabled and it seems that browsers tries to get the auth parameters from the user ('Sign in' form) first.